# Recibir parametros del IDP en el SP con PHP

Tags: php, apache, saml, adfs

He configurado un servidor SP con Shibboleth y Apache, la comunicación con el IDP es correcta, pero no recibo ningún dato en PHP después de hacer login.

Busco en las variables $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_SESSION, y $_SERVER, pero no consigo ver los parámetros que me envía el IDP.

Si accedo a la URL "https://mydomain.ext/Shibboleth.sso/Session" el apartado de "Attributes" está vacio.

Me gustaría recibir los datos al código PHP en el SP para manejarlos. ¿Alguna idea?

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, al parecer la solución se encuentra en 2 pasos,

- Habilitar el envío de parámetros desde el IDP al SP,
- Modificar el fichero "attribute-map.xml", declarando los atributos con sus tipos correctos.

Siguiendo esta información;

https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPAddAttribute

y esta;

https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPAttributeExtractor

Nos dará pistas sobre cómo debemos modificar nuestro archivo "atribute-map.xml", en mi caso me quedó así;

```
<Attributes xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:attribute-map" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Attribute name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" id="emailaddress" />
    <Attribute name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" id="nameidentifier" />
    <Attribute name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" id="givenname" />
    <Attribute name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname" id="surname" />
</Attributes>
```

Espero que también os ayude a vosotros. Salu2